# When fetching data from the API, the text is Arabic It looks like this inside a flutter

Tags: json, flutter, arabic

When fetching data from the API, the text is Arabic
It looks like this inside a flutter

```
I/flutter ( 5741): name name name     Ù†Ù‚Øµ Ø§Ù„ÙÙŠØªØ§Ù…ÙŠÙ† D ÙŠØ³Ø¨Ø¨ Ù…Ø±Ø¶:
I/flutter ( 5741): name name name     Ù…Ù† Ù‡Ùˆ Ø§Ù„ØµØ­Ø§Ø¨ÙŠ Ø§Ù„Ø¬Ù„ÙŠÙ„ Ø§Ù„Ø°ÙŠ Ø§Ù‡ØªØ² Ø¹Ø±Ø´ Ø§Ù„Ø±Ø­Ù…Ù† Ù„Ù…ÙˆØªÙ‡ ØŸ
I/flutter ( 5741): name name name     Ù…Ø¯Ø© Ø§Ù„Ø´ÙˆØ·  Ø§Ù„Ø®Ø§Ù…Ø³ Ù„ÙƒØ±Ø© Ø§Ù„Ø·Ø§Ø¦Ø±Ø©
I/flutter ( 5741): name name name     Ø¹Ø¯Ø¯Ø§Ù„Ø®Ù„Ø§ÙŠØ§ Ø§Ù„Ù†Ø§ØªØ¬Ø© Ø¹Ù† Ø§Ù„Ø§Ù†Ù‚Ø³Ø§Ù… Ø§Ù„Ù…ÙŠØªÙˆØ²ÙŠ (Ø§Ù„Ù…ØªØ³Ø§ÙˆÙŠ):
```

Comment: Please provide some code. How are you receiving your data? What is the data expected to look like?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Future<void> fetchQuestion(int id) async {
    late Question question;
    print('fetchQuestion fetchQuestion ');
    var url = Uri.http(basicUrl, '/questions/${id}');
    List<int>? listQuestionId = null;
    try {
      var responRes = await http.get(url);

      if (responRes.statusCode == 200) {
        final jsonResponRes = convert.jsonDecode(responRes.body) as Map;

        //currenntQuestion = jsonResponRes as Quest;
        print('name name name     ${jsonResponRes['name']}');

Comment: Please do not post long strings of code in a comment. It's unreadable. Edit your a question to provide all relevant details. What is the JSON you receive (literally, what are the bytes?), and what do you expect this to output?